# ¿Cómo cambiar color del menú seleccionado en menú hamburguesa de Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Tengo hecho con Xamarin.Forms un menú hamburguesa, el color de fondo se lo cambié sin problemas, el problema lo tengo en que cuando selecciono un menú quiero elegir otro color y que no salga el naranja predeterminado. Alguien puede decirme como hacerlo?

¡Gracias de antemano!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957076/579895) a ver si te vale

Comment: No, no me sirvió... gracias igualmente!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el siguiente link se encuentra la explicación: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20798/listview-selected-item-background-color

**EDICIÓN** (clarificando ejemplo)

Solo hay que definir

```
<resources>
  <color name="mycolor">#eaeaea</color>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     .....
   <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/mycolor</item>
   </style>

  </resources>
```

en tu tema, modificas el transparent con el color de tu preferencia.

Comment: Va encaminado por ahí el tema... el problema es que como tengo el color por un número hexadecimal me da el siguiente error:

    Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:colorActivatedHighlight' with value '@android:color/#EF9D37').

Y si le dejo solo el hexadecimal no aparece ningun color...

Comment: @Matias puse más claro el ejemplo, te recomiendo revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674183/storing-hex-color-values-in-strings-xml para saber más acerca del manejo de colores como xml

Comment: Ahora si, perfecto... muchas gracias!!